# Mobile Broadband not working in 12.10

Tags: mobile-broadband

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and connected to MTS MBlaze. I get the message "Connection Established". But when I open Firefox, I can't view any web page.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu @Vineet Billorey. Excellent quesion - keep it up. Have a nice day and best of luck with answering your question.

Comment: wv dial connects the internet but the software center and notification bar doesnot reecognizes it... they say internet not conected... any1 have solution for that??

Comment: You need to hit `Ctrl + C` to disconnect. Yes as you correctly say that network manager will say not connected but all your applications would work.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter problems with mobile broadband too, I use `wvdial` to connect to the internet with MTS. I wrote a [blog post](http://nikhilbhardwaj.in/2012/05/06/mts-settings-for-ubuntu-12-04/) on how you can get that working.

Hope it helps, feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.